# Almacenar una Consulta SQL MySQL en JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, base-de-datos, jsonarray

la consulta es la siguiente tengo esta consulta:
[image: Consulta SQL]

Edit> Agregado Consulta en PHP:

```
 if (!($resultado = $conexion->prepare("
   SELECT
     facturas.*, renglones.producto,
     renglones.cantidad, renglones.precio_unitario,
     renglones.total, renglones.porcentaje_iva
   FROM facturas
   INNER JOIN renglones
     ON idfactura = facturas.id AND facturas.id = $id
 "))){
        echo "Fallo la Preparación";
 };

    if (!($resultado->execute())) {
        echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
    } else $resultado = $resultado->get_result();

    $a = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
```

La recorro a través de un foreach o un while.

El punto es que no logro hacer el json_encode();

Y que me quede algo asi:

```
{
"id": 3,
"numero": "0003",
"contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
"rif": "1263334486",
"fecha": "2018-10-11",
"monto": "375.00",
"producto": ["1":"PAN DULCE", "2":"PAN SALADO", "3":"QUESO"],
"cantidad": ["1":"10.00, "2":"10.00", "3":"0.50"],
"precio_unitario": ["1":"7.00, "2":"5.00", "3":"500.00"],
"total": ["1":"70.00", "2":"55.00", "3":"250.00"],
"porcentaje_iva": "16.00"
}
```

Me esta costando sacar este JSON, probablemente algún problema de lógica en el foreach o while (he intentado con ambos).

El archivo JSON siempre termina quedándome asi:

```
{
"id": 3,
"numero": "0003",
"contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
"rif": "1263334486",
"fecha": "2018-10-11",
"monto": "375.00",
"producto": "PAN DULCE",
"cantidad": "10.00",
"precio_unitario": "7.00",
"total": "70.00",
"porcentaje_iva": "16.00"
}
```

Pues al final tengo que decodificarlo y pasarlo por una tabla. Esto lo he realizado únicamente en PHP, pero necesito que sea a través de JSON. Y almacenar el archivo JSON. Agradesco toda la ayuda posible prestada.

```
while ($a = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $total = $a['total'] - ($a['total']*0.16);
            $subtotal += $total;
            $total_iva += $a['total'] * $iva;
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td class='renglon_detalle'>".$a['cantidad']."</td>
                    <td class='renglon_detalle'>".$a['producto']."</td>
                    <td class='renglon_detalle'>".$a['precio_unitario']."</td>
                    <td class='renglon_detalle'>".$a['porcentaje_iva']."</td>
                    <td class='renglon_detalle renglon_precio' colspan='2'>".$total."</td>
                </tr>
                    ";   
                };
```

Y el resultado:

[image: Factura]

> EDIT> Cambios en el JSON luego de aplicar la solución de @shadow:

```
[
{
    "id": "3",
    "0": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "1": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "2": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "3": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "4": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "5": "375.00",
    "producto": "PAN DULCE",
    "6": "PAN DULCE",
    "cantidad": "10.00",
    "7": "10.00",
    "precio_unitario": "7.00",
    "8": "7.00",
    "total": "70.00",
    "9": "70.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00",
    "10": "16.00"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "0": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "1": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "2": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "3": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "4": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "5": "375.00",
    "producto": "PAN SALADO",
    "6": "PAN SALADO",
    "cantidad": "10.00",
    "7": "10.00",
    "precio_unitario": "5.00",
    "8": "5.00",
    "total": "55.00",
    "9": "55.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00",
    "10": "16.00"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "0": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "1": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "2": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "3": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "4": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "5": "375.00",
    "producto": "QUESO",
    "6": "QUESO",
    "cantidad": "0.50",
    "7": "0.50",
    "precio_unitario": "500.00",
    "8": "500.00",
    "total": "250.00",
    "9": "250.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00",
    "10": "16.00"
}
]
```

> Como quedo mi consulta SQL en PHP:

```
if (!($consulta = $conexion->prepare("
  SELECT
   facturas.*, renglones.producto,
   renglones.cantidad, renglones.precio_unitario,
   renglones.total, renglones.porcentaje_iva
  FROM facturas
  INNER JOIN renglones
    ON idfactura = facturas.id AND facturas.id = :id
  "))) {
     echo "Fallo la Preparación";
   };

   if (!($consulta->execute([':id' => $id]))) {
     echo "Fallo la ejecución de la consulta";
   }

   $resultado = JSON_ENCODE($consulta->fetchAll(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   $archivo = 'factura.json';
   file_put_contents($archivo, $resultado);

   var_dump($resultado);
```

> EDIT>FINALIZADO CON LA AYUDA DE @shadow

```
$resultado = JSON_ENCODE($consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

> y así quedo mi JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "producto": "PAN DULCE",
    "cantidad": "10.00",
    "precio_unitario": "7.00",
    "total": "70.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "producto": "PAN SALADO",
    "cantidad": "10.00",
    "precio_unitario": "5.00",
    "total": "55.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "numero": "0003",
    "contribuyente": "ARIADNA PADRON",
    "rif": "1263334486",
    "fecha": "2018-10-11",
    "monto": "375.00",
    "producto": "QUESO",
    "cantidad": "0.50",
    "precio_unitario": "500.00",
    "total": "250.00",
    "porcentaje_iva": "16.00"
}
]
```

y pude vaciar en mi tabla tranquilamente. GRACIAS!

Comment: agrega la consulta como la ejecutas en php

Comment: Ya la agregue @shadow

Comment: que usas mysqli o PDO?

Comment: Mysqlli. Use prepare() por que lo vi y hablaba de eficiencia, rapidez y mayor seguridad a la hora de SQL INJECTION, y aunque para serte sincero, no se si esta bien implementado o no, es decir, si es debido implementarlo o no.

Comment: ok dame unos minutos y te respondo

Comment: Quedo a la espera. Y Gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo  usar PDO, para lo cual te dejo un ejemplo explicado

```
<?php

$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;port=3307", "root", "password");

$id = 1;
$consulta = $conexion->prepare("
  SELECT
    facturas.*, renglones.producto,
    renglones.cantidad, renglones.precio_unitario,
    renglones.total, renglones.porcentaje_iva
  FROM facturas
  INNER JOIN renglones
    ON idfactura = facturas.id AND facturas.id = :id
  ");
$consulta->execute([':id' => $id]);

$resultado = JSON_ENCODE($consulta->fetchAll());

var_dump($resultado);
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

1. declaro mi conexión a PDO donde opcionalmente puedo indicar el puerto de conexión
2. meto la consulta dentro del método `prepare()`
3. Al momento de pasar datos dinámicos es decir que los manda el usuario, debemos usar marcadores de nombre que son así `:name` para el caso de **PDO** de este modo minimizamos el caso de *SQL INJECTION*
4. Dentro del método execute meto en forma de array asociativo el marcador de nombre `:id` y lo igualo con la variable que esta mandando el usuario que en este caso es `$id`
5. Dentro de una nueva variable llamada `$result` la igualo con el método `JSON_ENCODE` donde meto la variable `$consulta` que a su vez accede al método `fetchAll()` con esto convertimos nuestra consulta a formato JSON
6. Para poder ver el resultado de la consulta, hacemos un `var_dump()` y el resultado debería ser como la estructura que buscas

Comment: Gracias @shadow sin duda me devolvió algo mucho mas cercano. Podria funcionarme que guarde cada Renglon por separado, pero ahora veo duplicidad en el JSON, todo se escribe dos veces.  Dejo arriba los cambios en el JSON para que veas como quedo.

Comment: Resuelto, si me sirvió, solo agregue fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) y me lo devolvio de un modo mas agradable. Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda @shadow.

Por la manera en que lo abarcaste y explicaste claramente tu recomendación.

Comment: Otra pregunta que dejo al aire. 

Habría alguna manera de hacerlo como había especificado al principio, es decir, que tomase el ID, y creara un solo registro con ese ID donde se almacenara directamente en ("producto" :  algunProducto), todos los productos de ese ID? (Sin tener que duplicar en mi caso 3 veces la misma información).

Y si de poder realizarse, seria mas eficiente?